# Problema con SELECT PHP

Tags: pdo, select, foreach

**Método Mostrar**

```
 public function mostrar(){
            $conexion = new Conexion();
            $con = $conexion->Conectar();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM libros";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }
```

**Llamado del método**

```
$obj_libro = new LibroControlador();
        $listar = $obj_libro->mostrar();
        //var_dump($listar);


<?php foreach($listar as $lista){?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $lista->getID_libro();;?></td>
                    <td><?php  echo $lista->getNombre();?></td>
                    <td><?php  echo $lista->getAutor();?></td>
                    <td><?php  echo $lista->getFecha();?></td>
                    <td><?php  echo $lista->getStock();?></td>
                    <td><?php  echo $lista->getStockMin();?></td>
                    <td>
                       <button class="btn btn-warning" title="Editar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                       <button class="btn btn-danger" title="Eliminar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEliminar"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php }?>
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando llamo al método `mostrar()`, no devuelve ningún registro.
Verifiqué con `var_dump()` y resulta que viene un array vacío.

Comment: Te indica algún error, seguro que se inicia la conexión?

Comment: Prueba a imprimir el resultado de esa consulta sql -> `$resultado = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($resultado);`

Comment: Me lanza un array vacío

Comment: Ya que quieres organizar tu código, escribiendo clases, métodos, etc... piensa en **controlar los errores**. ¿Qué cosas pueden fallar? La conexión puede ser nula, la consulta puede tener un error de sintaxis, la consulta puede venir vacías porque no se encontraron datos... etc. No hay ningún control al respecto en tu código. Debes ser lo más *pesimista* posible si quieres escribir un código robusto que responda a todo lo que pueda salir mal y no se quede en el limbo o se rompa.